# What is the difference between "yes" and "all" and "local" for "AllowTcpForwarding in sshd config file?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

The other day, I was trying to connect to a DB using a Workbench.
I was unable to connect to my DB using an SSH tunnel but I was able to connect locally if I simply SSH'ed to my server.

After reading the log, I found the following error `"refused local port forward": originator 127.0.0.1 port 0, target localhost port 3306`

While reviewing my config, I found that AllowTcpForwarding was set to "yes".

Why does setting "AllowTcpForwarding" to "local" resolved my problem ? In my mind, yes means ... yes. The manual is not helping me much:

> Specifies whether TCP forwarding is permitted. The available options are yes (the default) or all to allow TCP forwarding, no to prevent all TCP forwarding, local to allow local (from the perspective of ssh(1))

Another piece of information is that I could make it working by enabling X11Forwarding (which makes no sense for me as jdbc has nothing to do with X server?)

To sum it up:
Config that does **not** work:

```
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

Configs that does work:

```
X11Forwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

or

```
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding local
```

Comment: `yes` or `all` allows both `local` and `remote` tcp forwarding, so if `local` works, `yes` should also work, unless there is a bug somewhere. your error message is from openssh/serverloop.c perhaps you could add a debug message there

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will do my best to add a debug message today